# Is it possible to have a local copy of google maps shared with all users of my application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building an application where in I display a google map with custom markers to the end users.
I have custom data about various spots in the city, which I store in my DB.
When a user logs in - based on his queries I query my DB and display markers on the google maps.

I was wondering if there is an option to not store custom data in my DB. Instead

1. Can I have an instance of map which will store the custom markers
2. Other users using this App will access the same instance of the map and the same set of markers displayed.
3. Users can add/remove a marker and this will get reflected to all users.

I am able to achieve all of the above by keeping data related to custom marker in my local DB. I just want to know if google maps provides me option to use a shared local instance across various users of map

Comment: And where would the markers be stored then?

Comment: This probably violates TOS regarding logging in.

Comment: [See here](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) Section 9.1.1 General Rules. for Google's Tos